# Correct way to get weighted average of concrete array-values along continous interval

Tags: arrays, intervals, weighted-average

I've been looking for a while onto websearch, however, possibly or probably I am missing the right terminology.

I have arbitrary sized arrays of scalars ...

```
array = [n_0, n_1, n_2, ..., n_m]
```

I also have a function `f->x->y`, with `0<=x<=1`, and `y` an interpolated value from `array`. Examples:

```
array = [1,2,9]

f(0)    = 1
f(0.5)  = 2
f(1)    = 9

f(0.75) = 5.5
```

My problem is that I want to compute the average value for some interval `r = [a..b]`, where `a E [0..1]` and `b E [0..1]`, i.e. I want to generalize my interpolation function `f->x->y` to compute the average along `r`.

My mind boggles me slightly w.r.t. finding the right weighting. Imagine I want to compute `f([0.2,0.8])`:

```
array     -->  1       |      2       |      9
[0..1]    -->  0.00   0.25   0.50   0.75  1.00
[0.2,0.8] -->        ^___________________^
```

The latter being the range of values I want to compute the average of.

Would it be mathematically correct to compute the average like this?: <sup>*</sup>

```
          1 * (1-0.8)       <- 0.2 'translated' to [0..0.25]
        + 2 * 1
avg =   + 9 * 0.2           <- 0.8 'translated' to [0.75..1]
       ----------
            1.4             <-- the sum of weights
```

Comment: Upon writing up this question, I got some insight and I am now quite sure that I am correct (but not 100%).

Comment: Okay, I am pretty sure now I am correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average#Mathematical_definition . I'll write up an answer :)

Comment: I am guilty of cross-posting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528267/what-is-the-average-value-of-number-range-along-interval .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct.

In your example, your interval's length is `0.6`. In that interval, your number `2` is taking up `(0.75-0.25)/0.6 = 0.5/0.6 = 10/12` of space. Your number `1` takes up `(0.25-0.2)/0.6 = 0.05 = 1/12` of space, likewise your number `9`.

This sums up to `10/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 = 1`.

For better intuition, think about it like this: The problem is to determine how much space each array-element covers along an interval. The rest is just filling the machinery described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average#Mathematical_definition .